# Eclipse Modeling Framework - Workflow?

Tags: eclipse, emf, xpand

I have the following question. I have got an EMF Project with a M2M Transformation which uses ATL as Technology. Then I have a project that uses XPand for Code Generation. I want to do the following workflow.

Model A --  --> Model B ----> Code

How can I realize that, the Problem is, that I have two projects and I must copy my model and metamodel to the other project. Is there any Technology to model such a workflow as described above?

Thank you,
clemens

Answer (score 1):

You should give a look to MWE2 : http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation.html#MWE2

You'll be able to describe the m2m execution and the xpand generation in your mwe2 workflow.

You'll also need to launch the atl transformation from java, see this: https://github.com/101companies/101repo/blob/master/contributions/atl/src/atl/RunTransfoJava.java

regards

Answer (score 0):

If you can write a corresponding ant script, you can run it with the tycho-application run during a tycho build. ATL has ant tasks, and so does EMF. This is a bit of a hack though, and MWE is a more coordinated way to do it.